# External HDD shows 0B capacity, 0 sectors

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have an 1 TB external HDD drive (Western Digital) that is not recognized properly in Windows nor Linux nor Mac.

I can manipulate it in Linux only with `gdisk`. In Windows the only tool that sees the disk is `diskpart` and it shows 0B capacity (other tools don't recognize it or fail trying to do something).

In Linux (Ubuntu) `fdisk` doesn't show it, `gdisk` can access it (I know the device name `/dev/sdc` because in "disks" the disk appears as no media but with the device name) but says that the drive has 0 sectors. That's why I can't write the MBR or GTP table – there is not enough capacity.

PD: On `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` it shows that there's an error on diagnostic page asked 1 but got 0.

If you need screenshots of the things that I wrote here, please tell me.

Comment: Sounds like a bad drive...

Comment: But its almost new, i just take it out when it was copying last time because it was taking too much time and i had cancelled the copy.

Comment: Almost new or not isn't relevant, failures can happen. The symptoms you're describing are indicitive of a hardware failure, either the physical drive is bad or the controller inside the enclosure. If it is under warranty, contact the manufacturer, if it isn't try removing the drive from the enclose and connecting it to a known working USB-SATA adapter or directly to the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your issues with the WD external HDD! :( I totally agree with @acejavelin regarding the fact that HDDs are sensitive and they could easily get damaged even during shipping. Since the drive is relatively new, **you shouldn't tamper with the enclosure because it would void its warranty**! The best thing to do is get in touch with the reseller's support or our [WD official customer support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=FMTdca) to send your RMA request. However, you need to first check [the warranty on the product here](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=hq8oOi). If it's still covered, you should get a replacement soon enough.

Hope this helps you. Best of luck!